# How to select distinct values after left outer join operation

Tags: sql-server

I want to select some values from three tables with aggregate function but without duplicates in one of the columns, for example:

```
select t3.ValueDesc as FeatureType,  
        count(t2.Strategic) as TotalCount
        ,t2.RequestID,t1.StoryID    --these are not needed, but put for better vision

from  tblRequests t2  
left outer join (select * from tblAgileMultiDD where Type=18) t3
    on t3.FormulaValue = t2.Strategic 
left outer join tblAgileStory t1 
    on t1.Feature = t2.RequestID  

where t2.RequestID > 0  
and t1.DemoStatus = 1  

group by t3.ValueDesc
     ,t2.RequestID, t1.StoryID    --these are not needed but put for better vision
order by t3.ValueDesc
```

And then it returns me something like this:

```
FeatureType     TotalCount  RequestID   StoryID
Protect Base    1           311         1629
Protect Base    1           311         1630
Protect Base    1           312         1631
Protect Base    1           312         1637
New Market      1           313         1640
New Market      1           313         1645
```

And if I comment out lines with ",t2.RequestID, t1.StoryID", it gives me the result:

```
FeatureType     TotalCount
Protect Base    4         
New Market      2
```

So, for each unique combination of RequestID and StoryID it returns new row. How to make it return new row only for each unique RequestID regardless to StoryID?
So I want this query to result like this:

```
FeatureType     TotalCount
Protect Base    2          (for RequestID = 311, 312)
New Market      1          (for RequestID = 313)
```

Putting word "distinct" at the beginning doesn't take effect on it.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: What about count(Distinct t2.Strategic), or rather count distinct based on the requestID

Comment: I think you've already found a solution: remove `t2.RequestID` and `t1.StoryID` from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct FeatureType,TotalCount from (
    select t3.ValueDesc as FeatureType,  
            count(t2.Strategic) as TotalCount
            ,t2.RequestID
            -- ,t1.StoryID    --these are not needed, but put for better vision

    from  tblRequests t2  
    left outer join (select * from tblAgileMultiDD where Type=18) t3
        on t3.FormulaValue = t2.Strategic 
    left outer join tblAgileStory t1 
        on t1.Feature = t2.RequestID  

    where t2.RequestID > 0  
    and t1.DemoStatus = 1  

    group by t3.ValueDesc
         ,t2.RequestID
          -- , t1.StoryID    --these are not needed but put for better vision
) as T
```

order by t3.ValueDesc

could you try this.